# Downloading AzureML model raised SSL error

Tags: azure, ssl, download, azure-sdk-python

I have very strange error :

If I would like to download one model I get

```
python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py in recv_into(self, *args, **kwargs)
    303         try:
--> 304             return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
    305         except OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError as e:
SSLError: ("read error: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_record', 'decryption failed or bad record mac')],)",)
```

But, if I download another model in same workspace download normally.

```
model = Model(ws, 'model1')
model.download(target_dir=os.getcwd() + '/outputs/1/', exist_ok=True)
# this download normaly

model = Model(ws, 'model2')
model.download(target_dir=os.getcwd() + '/outputs/2/', exist_ok=True)
# This give me an SSL error
```

Some points:

- This model already worked, but suddenly doesn't wont to download
- My network is probably not a problem, because else the first model wouldn't download,...

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed odd. I assume that it this is consistently reproducing between model1 and 2. Which version of openssl are you using?

```sh
python -c "import sys; print(sys.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
```